# Measuring response time of external systems on Apache web server

Tags: apache-2.2

Our website has been developed in PHP, running on Apache web server. We use MySQL, Apache Solr, Memcached among other external systems.

I am looking for a server side tool / Apache module that will help us measure the response time of database, Solr and other systems while loading a page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't exist.  Any such module would need to be completely customized for the site using it.  For example, you use MySQL, Solr, and Memcahed, but some other site uses PGSQL, Redis, and APC caching.  It would be impossible for one module to support all of that.

The best you can really do is setup Icinga or similar to do some health checks.  You can combine that with one of the various graphing addons for it to generate response time graphs.  This will get you close, but it's only going to get per-server graphs, not per-page-load graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question.

Not the same that we were looking for, but XHProf by Facebook https://github.com/facebook/xhprof provided us with a lot of statistics, including the above.